# How to rewrite C# Linq query with state variable into T-SQL

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, t-sql

I have a Linq query (against in-memory objects) which uses local `dateTimeLast`  variable to keep state:

```
IEnumerable<CacheEntry> entries = await db.Caches.OrderBy(e => e.Time).ToListAsync();
DateTime? dateTimeLast = null;

IEnumerable<CacheEntry> progression = entries.Where(e =>
{
    bool isProgress = ((dateTimeLast == null) || (dateTimeLast >= e.DateAndTime));

    if (isProgress)
        dateTimeLast = e.DateAndTime;

    return isProgress;
});

var result = progression.ToList();
```

How can I rewrite that Linq query into plain a T-SQL (SQL Server) query?

I do not know how to translate `Where` condition with state variable `dateTimeLast` in T-SQL.

Source table grew a lot in size and loading all into memory is too slow now.

Of course query is very simplified so there would be additional `WHERE` conditions, like `SELECT * FROM Caches WHERE <search_condition> ORDER BY Time`, but they are not the issue.

Source table `Caches` has 2 columns: `Time`, `DateAndTime` (they are no related).

For example I was looking at `LAG` function, but not useful.

Comment: If the query is working fine, I recommend to look at generated SQL with LINQPad or other tools similar like that. It will save your time to write SQL statements. Note that `DateTime? dateTimeLast` definition is equivalent to `DECLARE @dateTimeLast DATETIME` in SQL.

Comment: maybe you can function or storeprocedure

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Query is in-memory so no SQL is generated. I know how to declare the variable, but do not know how to write rest of SQL query.

Comment: @OMANSAK Any idea how the content of function or storedprocedure would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with some SQL code using a combination of:

- A temporary @dateTimeLast variable, as suggested by Tetsuya Yamamoto
- A temporary table to store the valid rows
- A cursor to iterate the rows in the table

You can use the following code as guidance (**NOT tested**, please consider it as pseudocode), it assumes that the name of the table is `entries` and that it has an integer `id` column:

```
DECLARE @dateTimeLast DATETIME
DECLARE @isProgress BIT
DECLARE @id INT
DECLARE @entryDateTime DATETIME

SELECT TOP 0 * INTO #temp FROM entries

DECLARE the_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT Id, DateAndTime FROM entries ORDER BY Time

OPEN the_cursor  

FETCH NEXT FROM the_cursor INTO @id, @entryDateTime  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
  SELECT @isProgress = (@dateTimeLast IS NULL) OR (@dateTimeLast >= @entryDateTime)
  IF @isProgress 
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #temp (SELECT * FROM entries WHERE id = @id)
    @dateTimeLast = @entryDateTime
  END
  FETCH NEXT FROM the_cursor INTO @id, @entryDateTime  
END 

CLOSE the_cursor  
DEALLOCATE the_cursor 

SELECT * FROM #temp
```

Another option is to create the temporary table to store just the ids of the rows, and in the end do something like `SELECT * FROM entries WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM #temp)`

Comment: After minor corrections of pseudocode I managed to get expected result. Still performance is not best, but of course much better then in-memory Linq. Any hints how to improve performance?